# Included layout covers parent layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

My main activity has a Toolbar within an AppBarLayout and an include below that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.zhephyr.somedaytoday.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_chrono_tab"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The included layout is a RelativeLayout with a TabLayout connected to a ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ChronoSwipeViewActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorVariant"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/chrono_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:background="@color/colorVariant"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/chrono_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue I am currently running into is that The included layout sits on top of my main layout filling the entire screen. I cannot see the Toolbar because it is being covered. I want the included layout to fill only the area below the toolbar. I've tried placing `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in both layouts and in the include with no avail. Anyone know what's going on?

**Update**

The activity being shown is this:

[image: shown activity]

This activity should be shown within this one and with out the app title:

[image: main activity]

Comment: Change the root of your included layout to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Since CoordinatorLayout is internally FrameLayout. the match_parent attribute of included layout covers on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the root of your included layout to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Currently, it is `match_parent` so it will take the height of the parent filling the entire screen.

You will also want to add to your `<include>`, `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"` to place it below the toolbar. By default, `RelativeLayout` places `Views` in the top-left so adding this property will tell it to start your included layout below the toolbar.

Note the last two lines in the below code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ChronoSwipeViewActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

in include tag of main layout

```
<include layout="@layout/activity_chrono_tab"
     android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>
```

Comment: When I try to do this, there is an error that says `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_below' with value '@id/toolbar').

Comment: Make sure you spelled it how it's declared above in your toolbar layout but that should work. You could try adding a `+` here `@+id/toolbar` but you shouldn't need to and it's not really the best way. Maybe try cleaning your project too. That is sometimes necessary when making xml changes. If that still doesn't work, I could try taking a look at your xml files.

Comment: Still did not work. Edited question to add more information.

Comment: Also, the two xml layouts I added are the only two in question.

Comment: My apologies, you want to add `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"` to the `<include>` tag not the root of the included file.

Comment: Still no luck. It also required me to add `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`. The included layout is attached to an activity is that helps. The activity extends `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: What do you mean by "still no luck"? Is anything different? You shouldn't be getting the error that it can't find that resource id now.

Comment: Right. The error is no more. But the layout is still sitting on top of the old one. And I have changed the `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129828/discussion-between-codemagic-and-michael-wang).